# Kant's categorical imperative and casual sex. Why does casual sex necessarily involve using someone as a mere means?

Tags: ethics, kant, categorical-imperative, sexuality

I am writing a paper on Kant's principle and test of universalizability. It seems that the test can allow for morally permissible casual sex (i.e., sex outside the Kantian marriage), e.g., consider the maxim “In order to satisfy my sexual desire on this rare occasion in which I am highly stressed and very lonely, I shall visit a prostitute”. Moreover, the humanity formula (second formulation of the categorical imperative) might also permit prostitution and other forms of casual sex: it is not clear that engaging in such activity implies using a human being as a *mere* means; for example, I'm sure Kant condemns other forms of labour (e.g., farming, accounting, in which the worker is being treated as a means, but not necessarily a mere means).

I basically want someone with some knowledge of Kant (I'm new to Kant's moral philosophy) to tell me if I'm right in what I'm saying, and that it seems that Kant is almost hinting at sex as a special moral category (since manual labour is generally morally permissible, yet prositiution isn't). Of course, this would mean there is something wrong with Kant's theory generally, as the categorical imperative is, of course, unconditionial and does not make room for special moral categories. Or, at the very least, there is something inconsistent in Kant's views on morality and sex.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, "don't use others as a means to an end" requires a *very* generous interpretation to make any sense, because even something like buying a candy bar is using the cashier as a means to an end. Maybe you can interpret it as something like, "acting without consideration of whether the other person wants the outcome, too." But I don't know if Kant says that in so many words. And you can't respect the wishes of others in all things, because the freedom of one person is often in conflict with the freedom of others.

Comment: The way I personally interpret Kant, any transaction with other humans who agree to it without coercion is not immoral. This covers many forms of sex and many forms of labor, though obviously not all forms. The key question is only whether the other person consents freely enough to the terms. Finding some partner for an activity mutually beneficial to both is different from treating another as a mere means.

Comment: Casual sex does not necessarily use the other person as means. But **usually** it does (eg sex workers).

Comment: Please elaborate on the 'hint' that sex is a special moral category? How do you get this impression? I might have an answer then. If manual labor is permissible, it is probably because it cannot be avoided? "*What is necessary is never unwise*" and all that. It is widely asserted that sex is not 'necessary' in the same way.

Comment: @causative As a matter of fact, the humanity formula (not merely as means...) comes down to respect of *rational* volition, ie. you don't have to consider *actual* wishes but you'll have to project your own volition *insofar it is rational* in Kant. Thus, you can even discard explicit wishes if they are irrational, ie. produced merely by our faculty of desire. Therefore, Kant's own moral philosophy and sex will be hard to bring together. Kantian thinking will probably be compatible if argued well.

Comment: In other words: Kant is in no way about changes of perspective and putting oneself in other people's shoes. It is purely about the internal differentiation between rational and desire-driven volition and acting only because the former is not in conflict with the latter. Therefore, the whole thing comes down to: can it be rationally willed to work as a prostitute?